CalendarList: list requires unnecessary sensitive scope
I'm building an app that ask a user to select their calendar from calendar list, and then we check for busy slots. We don't want to access calendars content, yet Google seems to require to use an elevated scope to access https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList.
Indeed, per their doc, the lowest scope they require is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly which falls under sensitive scope category in the consent screen...:

... when auth/calendar.calendarlist.readonly should be sufficient

I tried using calendarlist.readonly auth in the scope but I get error 403, which disappears if I use the calendar.readonly.
Any reason why and hope for change?

Does this answer your question? What's the difference between the Google Calendar API scopes - calendar.readonly and calendar.events.readonly?. Though events is not necessarily your question is all about. I do think that the logic applied to this answer will help you get clarification.

@Babanana i don't think that question is going to answer their question.

if you check the documentation for calendarlist.list
You will see to use this method requires one of the following scopes

which means that the lowest level scope you can use is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly
If you check Calendar API, v3 Scopes you will notice that there is no scope called https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendarlist.readonly
You have no chose if you want to use that method you must use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly you cant invent your own scopes we are limited by the scopes google gives use.  TBH its worse with drive i would love to have a scope that only gave me access to a single directory but no its all or nothing.

The auth/calendar.calendarlist.readonly scope I'm suggesting Google support actually does exist in the OAuth consent screen (I added a screenshot in my original post).

Scopes are not based upon a single method. They are based upon an entire api for the most part.   Also  i can guarantee 99% that Google is not going to read your question.

Makes sense for scope to be aligned to entire API by default, but seems method level scope would be a welcome improvement, to support use-cases such as mine.

None of Google apis have method level scopes.   This API is more than ten years old I wouldn't wait for them to change this
